# PhP form posts normally (data received on e-mail) but displays FORM.PHP PAGE NOT FOUND

Tags: php

Everything works well behind the scene but my clients see a Page not found after Posting a form.

The form.php must have been found otherwise the data wouldn't be parsed to my e-mail smoothly. I have a redirection page: thankpage.html, which is up and running well when I type its address directly.

what could be going on? any help please?

Comment: We have no way to tell you want's going wrong without seeing the code that's causing the problem

Comment: mysql_query($query);
 header("location:thankpage.html");
  mysql_close($con);

if(!$mail->Send()){
$mensagemRetorno = 'Erro ao enviar formulário: '. print($mail->ErrorInfo);
}else{
header("location:thankpage.html");
}

Answer (score 0):

Anyway,

Instead of calling the Thankpage.html from the form.php, I inserted the following into my "form" element in the contact.html page itself:

```
onsubmit="window.location.href='http://www.inglesparticular-sp.com/thankpage.html';"
```

So it is now:

```
<form role="form" id="contact-form" method="post" action="form.php" onsubmit="window.location.href='http://www.inglesparticular-sp.com/thankpage.html';">
```

Somehow it's all working well and I have no "PAGE NOT FOUND" messages!!!

Sorry if I wasn't clear on the question, it's my first one as you can see... cheers!

Comment: Doing that is just going to skip over whatever you were doing in `form.php`. So if that page was inserting the data into your database, for example, that now isn't happening.

Comment: It is... everything is fine now!!! I have a thank page AND the data is coming through...